# Dynatree initial load with children

Tags: lazy-evaluation, children, dynatree

I have a lazy loading DynaTree in the lastest version 1.2.4 and get the challange, to provide the path to the current selected node. 
I do a loop over the root nodes to build the first level of the tree. After clicking one of the root nodes, the tree expand and select via lazy loading the next elements. 
Now the element in the 3rd dimension of the tree is known, but how i provide the affected nodes in the JSON structure?
A simple add to the end will also add the elements in the root tree.

```
$(function(){
        // Attach the dynatree widget to an existing <div id="tree"> element
        // and pass the tree options as an argument to the dynatree() function:
        $("##tree").dynatree({
            clickFolderMode: 3,
            persist: false,
            autoCollapse: true,
            onActivate: function(node) {
                // A DynaTreeNode object is passed to the activation handler
                // Note: we also get this event, if persistence is on, and the page is reloaded.
                if( node.data.href ){
                    // use href and target attributes:
                    window.location.href = node.data.href;                  
                }

            },
            onLazyRead: function(node){
                node.appendAjax({url: "#intranetpath#remote/lopTreeLoader.cfc?method=getNodes",
                                   data: {"key": node.data.key, // Optional url arguments
                                          "mode": "all"

                                          },
                                   // (Optional) use JSONP to allow cross-site-requests
                                   // (must be supported by the server):
            //                      dataType: "jsonp",
                                   success: function(node) {
                                       // Called after nodes have been created and the waiting icon was removed.
                                       // 'this' is the options for this Ajax request
                                       },
                                   error: function(node, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {                                    
                                       // Called on error, after error icon was created.
                                       },
                                   cache: false // Append random '_' argument to url to prevent caching.
                                  });
            },
            children: [ // Pass an array of nodes.
                <cfloop query="qDivision">
                {   key:"#qDivision.obj_uuid#" ,
                    title: "#qDivision.f_division_name#", 
                    activate:false, 
                    expand:#qDivision.expand#, 
                    select:false, 
                    isLazy:true,
                    <cfif qDivision.clickable>
                        addClass:"boldText",
                        href: "/program.helios/lop/index.cfm?obj_uuid=#qDivision.obj_uuid#",
                    </cfif>
                    icon:"../../skin/icons/idivision.gif"}

                    <cfif qDivision.currentrow NEQ qDivision.recordcount>,</cfif>
                </cfloop>



            ]
        });
    });
```

How I can initialize the tree with all nodes in the direct path to the selected node?

Answer (score 0):

A child object may in turn contain a `children` property:

```
 children: [ // Pass an array of nodes.
                <cfloop query="qDivision">
                {   key:"#qDivision.obj_uuid#" ,
                    title: "#qDivision.f_division_name#", 
                    activate:false, 
                    children: [{title: "foo"}, ...]
```